# Baking combined vs baking individual map

Tags: texturing, baking

I am confused with the combined baking mode, the combined mode has every map combined together let's say normal map, usually, I bake single normal map from high poly to low poly by creating low poly in advance, but when I want to bake texture, I do not have the low poly created then my question is, what is the difference between the combined mode normal information and a single normal map?